# LSI Megaraid alarm - clearing hotspare

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

I have several Supermicro servers with LSI Megaraid controllers, 9266-8i. One recently lost a drive; I replaced it as usual, but it is still beeping on reboot. It is set up as RAID 10 + hotspare.

`MegaCli64 -AdpEventLog -GetEvents -f events.log -aALL && cat events.log` shows me:

```
Event Description: Global Hot Spare created on PD 08(e0xfc/s0) (global,rev)
Event Description: Reminder: Potential non-optimal configuration due to drive PD
                    08(e0xfc/s0) commissioned as emergency spare
```

Since the beep pattern is 1 second on, 3 seconds off, which is the code for "SPEAKER_HOTSPARE_ENTRY - A hot spare drive has completed the rebuild process and has been brought into the array", I assume this is the root of the problem. I have updated to the latest firmware, since the release notes mentioned the "Potential non-optimal configuration" message, but no change.

Anyone have an idea on how to clear this?

Answer (score 5):

Source: IBM tip [H206526](https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5091562)

> There is no functional impact. To prevent the message from appearing
>   in the system event logs:
>
> - Open MegaRAID Storage Manager.
> - Select Tools --> Monitor Configure Alerts.
> - Select Change Individual Events.
> - Highlight event ID 406.
> - Deselect the System log check box.

Comment: I'm using this but I really hate to disable a valid warning, would love to have a real fix instead. No more hardware RAID for me, ZFS from now on

Comment: I have it set up this way but still getting an alarm on reboot and a message about hot-spare

Answer (score 2):

I have LSI controller, RAID 10 with four disks.  One disk went bad, hot-swap replace -> automatically set hot spare flag on new disk and got same warning as above. Turn machine off, physically remove replacement disk, separately did quick format to unset RAID participation, replaced disk and turned machine on.  Automatically found disk and started rebuild into RAID with unset hot spare flag.

Trick seems to be finding time when machine can be shut down for cold-swap with fresh disk.

Comment: I always thought that hotspare means you can replace disk on the fly without any downtime. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 2):

By default, copyback feature is turned on and this is why the problem is happening, the copyback needs to be completed.

Source Support article from Broadcom: [MegaRAID controller still beeps after rebuild completes and VD is optimal if Copy Back is enabled](https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161502838/megaraid-controller-still-beeps-after-rebuild-completes-and-vd-i)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this situation when I replaced bad drive (in Raid 10 with four drives) with hot-swap.  LSI megaraid automatically set emergency spare flag during new drive build.

I cleared this by later removing the new drive with computer powered down, separately did a quick (re)format to clear the RAID data, then replacing drive prior to repower/boot.  The new drive was discovered fresh on boot and rebuilt into the RAID with emergency spare flag off.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in an old firmware version. Updating the firmware does not fix the issue because it is written in the card's configuration.

So it is necessary to backup all the data from the disks, save the configuration, wipe the configuration on the controller and restore the configuration.

Complete answer from Broadcom technical support:

> It is in the config data and there is data that is not getting cleared.
>
> Try setting factory defaults: `storcli /cx set factory defaults`
>
> If that does not work, backup the data and save, delete and restore the controller configuration:
>
> - Save config: `storcli64 /c0 get config file=c0.cfg`
> - Destroy corrupt config: `storcli64 /c0 delete config force`
> - Reload config: `storcli64 /c0 set config file=c0.cfg`
>
> Either that or leave copyback disabled.

I had the same issue, I ended up leaving copyback disabled because I could not afford to have to restore the whole server from backup.

Comment: Seriously? They want you to save / restore everything just to get rid of a unnecessary warning?

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing feature in MegaCLI / StorCLI: After an array has been restored by rebuilding the data of a failed drive onto a hot spare, there is no way, how the admin can decide on a case by case basis: "I want this hot spare now to become a permanent member of the array (and possible declare a new hot spare)" or "I want the data to be copied back to the (replaced) original disk".

It is only possible to make this decision before the rebuild has started, on a global basis for all arrays, by setting the controller's copyback flag to off. Unfortunately, I don't know, if that has backdraws, though, like making copybacks impossible, even, if one wants to perform them.